# Issue on Querying Google Maps Supported Places From HTML Select Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to query Supported Places on Google Map from an HTML Select Options List. Here is the list I am using.

```
<select class="selectpicker" class="span2" id="gPlaces">
 <optgroup label="Picnic">
   <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
   <option value="airport">Airport</option>
   <option value="amusement_park">Amusement Park</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

I tried to grab the options value by using this code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("gPlaces");
var strPlace = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

and use the "strPlace" in findPlaces() to set my query as:

```
var request = {
                bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
                types: [strPlace]
               };
```

but for whatever reason it is not working. I also tied to grab the select the value using jquery .ready()  as:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   alert( strPlace );
});
```

but this is what I am getting:

[image]

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Updated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;
        var boxpolys = null;
        var directions = null;
        var routeBoxer = null;
        var distance = null; // km
        var service = null;
        var gmarkers = [];
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var e = document.getElementById("gPlaces");
        var strPlace = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: where/when do you execute the lines that define `e` and `strPlace`?

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually I didn't execute them? I just declared them at the top of script. Please take a look at updated part of post

Comment: Wait, you're setting the value of `strPlace` "at the top of the script"? Not at the time you actually need the value? That code should not be run until you actually need the value - otherwise you won't be getting what the user has currently selected. (What would you expect the value of `e.selectedIndex` to be at the top of the script?) From the description it sounds like this should be set inside the `findPlaces()` function. Can you post a *complete* example?

Comment: This [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_RouteBoxerPlacesDropDown.html) uses a drop down list of place types.

Comment: Thanks again geocodeZip, just as always you have the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

- phrasing everything inside a `$(function() {...})` structure.
- attaching a 'change' event handler to the select menu, such that the Google Maps Supported Places query is executed whenever the user makes a selection.

Javascript :

```
$(function() {
    ...
    $("#gPlaces").on('change', function() {
        var strPlace = $(this).val();
        alert( strPlace );
        // Use `strPlace` and other vars here to build and execute
        // your Google Maps Supported Places query.
    });
    ...
});
```